# jquery find id attribute exists or not

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find all the elements of engagement_app which have ids and which do not have ids. What is wrong with the below code? It cannot find the ones with/without ids

```
jQuery('.engagement_data').each(function() {

   var engagement_app = $(this).find(".engagement_app").val();
   //if ($(this).find(".engagement_app").attr('id'))
   if ($(this).find(".engagement_app").is('[id]'))
   {
      console.log("in if1")
      console.log($(this).find(".engagement_app").attr('id'));
   }

   if ($(this).find(".engagement_app").not('[id]'))
   {
        console.log("id not found")
   }
});
```

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation to learn what `.not` actually does: http://api.jquery.com/not/. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery?rq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

use `!` instead of `not`

```
if (! $(this).find(".engagement_app").is('[id]')){
    console.log("id not found")
}else{
    console.log("in if1")
    console.log($(this).find(".engagement_app").attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `"all the elements of engagement_app"` (chilldren?) with and without id you should use something like that.

```
var els_with_id = $(this).find(".engagement_app *[id]")
```

and

```
var els_without_ids = $(this).find(".engagement_app *").not("[id]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('.engagement_app [id]')
```

To find all elements with ID, and

```
$('.engagement_app :not([id])')
```

To find all elements without ID.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates how this could work:

http://jsfiddle.net/qj3V7/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".engagement_app").each(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");

if(id==undefined)
{
  console.log("id not found")
}
else
{
  console.log("in if1");
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
}
});


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="engagement_data">
<div class="engagement_app" id="1">1</div>
    <div class="engagement_app">2</div>
    <div class="engagement_app" id="3">3</div>
    <div class="engagement_app">4</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```